# My Apps VideoStream won't play

Tags: android, video, stream

I've been trying to deploy a video player onto my app and i did it so far through a YouTube video. But from what he did his video played perfectly. for whatever reason I cannot get my video player to start the stream. I've tried different formats but none seem to work.

The code is given below

```
package com.example.user.tabfinal;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class videoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

ProgressDialog pd ;
VideoView videoView;
ImageButton btnPlay;

String URL = "http://31.210.87.4/film/fullmp4best/Assassin_s_Creed_Official_Trailer_2_2016.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    btnPlay = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity2.this);
    pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    pd.show();

        try{
            if(!videoView.isPlaying()){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);

                }
            });

            }else{
                videoView.pause();
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex){

        }

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pd.dismiss();
            mp.setLooping(true);
            videoView.start();
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Some suggestions: 1.) make sure that btnPlay's onClickListener is actually being set to your "videoActivity" class. (maybe you're setting that in the R.layout.activity_main2.xml? i'm not sure.) i was expecting to see something like btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this); in your onCreate method body. 2.) put some logging statements in your onClick method, especially into that empty catch block. an exception could be getting thrown and then swallowed by that catch block. something like: Log.e("MainActivity", "Something went wrong", Ex);

Comment: the class is named 'videoActivity' but then, in the onClick method, a new ProgressDialog is being constructed with 'mainActivity2.this'. did you mean to use 'videoActivity.this' instead? also, it's more conventional to name the class 'VideoActivity' instead of 'videoActivity'.

Comment: also make sure you have the INTERNET permission in your app's AndroidManifest.xml: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: Sorry guys. I changed the main activity name to not seem like a noob :P forgot to change the rest. Also i have given permissions via the manifests

Comment: did it ever work?

Comment: Unfortunately not :< P.s sorry for calling you guys. im new here and didnt realize you were answering my questions thus far xD

Comment: no worries. it's no problem. i think you are probably close to having it working.

Comment: Try a different basic video playback tutorial (a written one so you can test by pasting their shown code to avoid any possible mistakes)